# How to populate a cell depending on which rows mention the row's first cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table where the first cell names each row, e.g. `Company A, Company B, ...`. I also have a column that we'll call `Contracts With`. When I now write `Company B` into this column in `Company A`'s row, `Company B`s cell in this column should be populated with `Company A`. So, basically, populate the other cell of this relationship

Comment: You can prepopulate a column with a formula to do such a lookup (or show something else like a blank cell if nothing is found).  But if you enter a value in a cell, that replaces the formula in that cell.  If something changes and you delete the entry, you no longer have a formula there.  Also, is it possible to have multiple contracts with the same company?  If so, how should that be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Alex for the answer!

However, to actually get what I want, i.e. populating a row's cell with values from other cells, concatenated with ", ", when they are mentioned (partial match) in these rows, you can use the following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A2; $B$2:$B$10)); $A$2:$A$10; ""))
```

Whereby column A has the values (e.g. company names) that should populate column B. `ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A2; $B$2:$B$10))` ensures that partial matches also work, which can be replaced with `$B$2:$B$10 = $A2` for an exact match.

Comment: "to actually get what I want, i.e. populating a row's cell with values from other cells, concatenated with ", "," this would have been good information to include in the question

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry. I didn't formulate all the requirements properly. I thought it was implicit that I would like to mention more than one company, as firms generally have contract with more than one company

Answer (score 1):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$8,0)),"not entered")`

[image]

In this example the formula is in column `C`, copied down; data entry goes into column `D`.

Comment: Thank you! How can I then also populate Company A's column C and is it possible to enter multiple companies in col D (comma separated) with the cells still getting populated (e.g. D2 is "Company B, Company C", and C3 is "Company A" and C4 is "Company A")?

Comment: "How can I then also populate Company A's column C " -have 'Company A' show up in another record's column `D`

Comment: "is it possible to enter multiple companies in col D (comma separated)" - you're onto this is your own answer; the answer is yes and it would be based on an `IF` and some combination of `ISNUMBER`, `ISERROR`, `SEARCH` and/or `FIND`. As you have it. It would be a good idea to edit these additional specs into your question for future reference.